# Count number of events in 1 dataframe occuring before an event in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes that contain lists of events. For example df1 looks like:

```
Person ID Date of event

a         01/01/2016 13:30

a         01/02/2016 18:35

b         07/07/2016 12:15

b         07/08/2016 19:15
```

Df2 looks similar but has a list of different events e.g:

```
Person ID   Date of event2

a           01/12/2015 15:15

b           07/12/2015 18:15

b           11/12/2015 14:05

b           01/01/2017 16:30
```

What I need to be able to do is to have a column in df1 that shows me the number of events in df2 that Person ID has been involved with before the date in df1.

The desired output from the above would be:

```
Person ID   Date of event 1 Number of events from DF2

a           01/01/2016       1

a           01/02/2016       1

b           07/07/2016       2

b           07/08/2016       2
```

I've tried a number of things and suspect that the answers involves something to do with a pivot table on df2 and merging the results into df1 but I can't seem to quite get this right.

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by merging the dataframes together on personId, doing a filter and then counting.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['a', '01/01/2016 13:30'],
                   ['a', '01/02/2016 18:35'],
                   ['b', '01/07/2016 12:15'],
                   ['b', '01/08/2016 19:15']],
                  columns=['PersonId', 'EventDate'])

df1['EventDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['EventDate'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([['a', '01/12/2015 15:15'],
                   ['b', '07/12/2015 18:15'],
                   ['b', '11/12/2015 14:05'],
                   ['b', '01/01/2017 16:30']],
                  columns=['PersonId', 'EventDate'])

df2['EventDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['EventDate'])

df_temp = df1.merge(df2, on=["PersonId"], suffixes=("_event1", "_event2"))
df_temp = df_temp[df_temp.loc[:, 'EventDate_event1'] > df_temp.loc[:, 'EventDate_event2']]
df_temp = df_temp.groupby(['PersonId', 'EventDate_event1'], as_index=False).count()
print(df_temp)
```

To get

```
  PersonId    EventDate_event1  EventDate_event2
0        a 2016-01-01 13:30:00                 1
1        a 2016-01-02 18:35:00                 1
2        b 2016-01-07 12:15:00                 2
3        b 2016-01-08 19:15:00                 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `apply()` to select `df2`data that respect your conditions then use`len()`to get the size. Make sure to cast to datetime your dates using `pd.to_datetime()`. See below:

df1 and df2 preparation:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['a','01/01/2016 13:30'],
                    ['a','01/02/2016 18:35'],
                    ['b','07/07/2016 12:15'],
                    ['b','07/08/2016 19:15']], columns=['id','date1'] )
df1['date1'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date1'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([['a','01/12/2015 15:15'],
                    ['b','07/12/2015 18:15'],
                    ['b','11/12/2015 14:05'],
                    ['b','01/01/2017 16:30']], columns=['id','date2'] )
df2['date2'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['date2'])
```

code:

```
df1['count'] = df1.apply(lambda x: len(df2[(df2.date2 <= x.date1)&(df2.id==x.id)]),
                         axis='columns')
```

Result :

```
i. id          date1         count
0  a 2016-01-01 13:30:00      1
1  a 2016-01-02 18:35:00      1
2  b 2016-07-07 12:15:00      2
3  b 2016-07-08 19:15:00      2
```